# Node.js upload file into Buffer instead of /tmp

Tags: node.js, file-upload

In a Node.js app, is it possible to upload a file (`multipart/form-data`) directly into a buffer on the server instead of saving the file to the filesystem?

In psuedo code you typically do this with a file upload form

```
router.post('/upload', function(req, res, next){
  // file is saved to /tmp/dk3idkalel4kidkek
  // do some processing on the file
  // manually save file to /www/myapp/uploads/originafilename.ext
});
```

Is it possible to skip the part about saving the file to `/tmp` and just capturing the uploaded file as a Buffer and streaming it directly to the destination directory?

An example would be uploading an image, then optimizing the image, then saving it to it's intended destination. Can you just capture the incoming stream, optimize it then save it, all without the initial saving to the `/tmp` directory?

Comment: Have you looked into Express Multer?  It has a MemoryStorage option that should do what you want.

Comment: I have I didn't realize it had that. Thank you

Comment: Great, if this has helped you, please mark answered and upvote.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multer is a node.js middleware for handling multipart/form-data, which is primarily used for uploading files.  The memory storage engine stores the files in memory as Buffer objects. When using memory storage, the file info will contain a field called buffer that contains the entire file.

This should do exactly what you need.

You can read more  [here](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a little concerned about the warning of memory limits being reached if end users try to upload too many large files too quickly. Maybe I need to stick with local file storage instead.

Answer (score 1):

Multer module uses `busboy` for upload, so an alternative would be to use busboy for express: [connect-busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy)